# angular 2 subscribe to boolean from service

Tags: angular

I have a service that has a changing boolean value, I want to subscribe to that boolean change in a component. How can this be achieved?

here is my service...

```
private subBoolShowHideSource = new Subject<boolean>();

subBoolShowHide$ = this.subBoolShowHideSource.asObservable();


showHide(eventValue: boolean) {
  this.subBoolShowHideSource.next(eventValue);
  console.log("show hide service " + eventValue);
}
```

and here is the component I am trying to get to read the bool value...

```
boolShowGTMDetails: any;
subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private service: ShowHideService){
  this.subscription = this.service.subBoolShowHide$.subscribe(
    (data:boolean) => {
      this.boolShowGTMDetails = data,
      error => console.log(error),
      console.log("winner winner chicken dinner");
    }
  );
}
```

Basically the change detection isn't working, any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need `.asObservable()` on your subject. Don't see anything wrong with the rest...

Comment: I removed it and still nothing is being passed to my component :/

Comment: Are you calling `this.service.showHide()` anywhere? Subject doesn't emit anything until you call `next()`

Comment: Yes, in another component not shown. I am getting the value change in the service I just need to push the value into the component I showed above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I figured out my problem....

I had in both my components `providers:[ShowHideService],` this of course creates two different instances of the service. So I removed this from both components and simply call it once in my app.modules and everything is working properly.  Rookie move on my end *facePalm* -_-

Answer (score 3):

You have some formatting issues in your subscription. This should work:

```
   this.subscription = this.service.subBoolShowHide$.subscribe(
       (data:boolean) => { this.boolShowGTMDetails = data },
       error => console.log(error),
       () => console.log("winner winner chicken dinner")
   );
```

Comment: Try to comment this whole subscription and do `console.log(this.service.subBoolShowHide$)` and `this.service.subBoolShowHide$.do(console.log).subscirbe()`. Anything unexpected happening?

Comment: No nothing unexpected is happening when I add this. Is my problem that its in the constructor? my app loads and show that my bool is undefined, and then when I change the bool it is subscribed to, it never calls any of the code in my constructor again...

Comment: It should stay subscribed if you don't unsubscribe somewhere... Or if the component is destroyed (tho' I'm not sure about this, check anyway :).

Comment: You sir were correct I just had another issue that I didnt add to my code above, I will awarding you the points for your correct answer regardless :)